# Framer Motion animation not working in Next.js 13.4.19

Tags: next.js, framer-motion

I'm trying to add animations to my Next.js application using Framer Motion. However, I have a different file structure than most tutorials, and the animations aren't working as expected.

Here's my file structure:
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ55O.png)
I am using NextJS 13.4.19

I tried to animate my Navbar you can take a look at the code below

```
"use client";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0, y: 15 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0, y: 15 }}
        transition={{ delay: 0.25 }}
    >
      <div className="w-full h-[112px] bg-primary"></div>
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

And I imported this component in my page.js

```
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
    </>
  );
}
```

The animation does not work right !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Im dealing with the same issue, first I thought its relates to my IDE's version but still I did make the animation work properly by over looking my code.